# Using Google Maps Direction API into iOS app

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-directions-api

Basically i want to show Google map with direction overlay on top of it from one place to other and Direction instructions into UITableView (eg. 30Miles move left , 20 miles turn Right etc.)

Is it acceptable by Apple? I can get directions using

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/
```

Main requirement is show directions instructions for example Driving, Walking instructions into UITableView.

But not sure Apple will approve it .

IF not what other option we have to do so.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , the Google Direction APIs are acceptable by Apple . I have used the direction in my projects out of which some of the Apps have been submitted to AppStore .

Comment: So using Google Direction API you can show direction instructions into TableView for exaple?

Comment: Google APIs provide you direction instruction between two places in the form of XML & Json . Using the following XML or Json you can create your local array and using that array you can populate your tableview . I have done in the same way . Here is the example of Direction APIs between two places : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false

Comment: Yes thats fine. I was reading TnC. DO you have any app live which does this? I trust you but before putting my time into it i want to make sure.

Comment: Sorry friend I can't provide you the App link as it would be voilating my current employers rules & regulation . But as you can see the Json is coming in the example url I have provide you , you just need to parse that Json . Store the values for the key: @"html_instructions" into an array and by simply accessing that array you can fullfil your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

@Gaurav Rastogi,

find this message, I'm very happy, do you know this,

> according to the Google Terms & Conditions you're not allowed to use their directions/data on someone else's maps." copy somewhere.

Is it legal?

Comment: Can you please point me out the source document from where this is copied.